# Boot loop after updating Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04 with Katoolin

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, katoolin

Currently I have a non-functioning machine due to an Ubuntu update.
I updated my nvidia-display driver, I ran `sudo apt update`, and then I rebooted.

Now I can't enter UEFI, the grub boot menu or Ubuntu 18.04.

After boot I get the following screen. This screen loops with a black screen.

[image: black screen 1]

I can run Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get a terminal, which gives the following screen. This screen also loops with a black screen.

[image: black screen 2]
<sup>This console doesn't look like Ubuntu, however Katoolin did this to Ubuntu 18.04 and the question is how to undo it.</sup>

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.
On Ubuntu Katoolin is installed. Probably this explains the image shown in the second screen photo since I have two OSs installed in some sense.

My GPU is Nvidia RTX 2080Ti and I have an PCI-E wireless ethernet adapter installed.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18.X release, plus Kali is not Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc Rayman is not running Kali linux. He messed up his Ubuntu 18.04 by not disabling the Kali linux repositories that were added to his software sources by the Katoolin Python script when updating Ubuntu 18.04. For more information about the source of the second screen photo in the question see [How do I restore my system OS back to its original condition after attempting to install Kali linux tools onto Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018441/).

Comment: **Reviewers**: Please hover the mouse over the `katoolin` tag.

Comment: OP has Ubuntu 18.04 installed as clearly stated in the question. `katoolin` is a python script https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin

Answer (score 2):

#### Start Ubuntu from a virtual console

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only console, and you can run terminal commands from the console.

#### Warning about updates after installing Kali linux tools

The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

[image]

All kinds of problems can occur if you don't do this.

---

1. Make a backup copy of sources.list.

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
2. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano text editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Replace the entire contents of your existing sources.list with the following default 18.04 sources.list:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
   ```
4. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
5. Run this command after changing sources.list to refresh the list of available software. This is the most important step, so please don't skip it.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
6. Remove Katoolin.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
7. Reinstall the Ubuntu desktop system.

   ```
   sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
   ```
8. Temporarily enable os-prober in grub by setting `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` in `/etc/default/grub`.
9. Install grub to the MBR of your boot drive with these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install base-files/bionic-updates  
   sudo os-prober  
   sudo update-grub
   ```
10. Reboot.

    ```
    sudo reboot
    ```
11. For security reasons disable os-prober in grub by setting `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in `/etc/default/grub`.
12. Run autoremove.

    ```
    sudo apt autoremove
    ```
13. Install deborphan

    ```
    sudo apt install deborphan
    ```
14. Run `deborphan` to show a list of packages orphaned after uninstalling Katoolin. These orphaned packages are no longer necessary except if you are still using any of the packages that were installed by Katoolin. These packages are referred to as *Kali linux tools* by Katoolin which gives the user some warning about the mischief that installing these packages can cause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In order to stop the looping screen I remove the GPU and plugged the monitor to the motherboard. So far so good. I can now enter Windows 10 and I can see the grub menu.

I have followed the steps provided by karel.
Unfortunately I get stucked in step 6 since my network connection is not working.

ping 8.8.8.8 returns: "Connect: Network is unreachable"
I can access the internet on the very same machine if I boot into Windows 10.

So how can I move forward?

Comment: Run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to identify your networking device. Then I'll tell you how to download the correct driver. You can download the network driver packages manually by booting into Windows 10. Then boot Ubuntu if you can, and copy them over to the Ubuntu partition. If you can't boot into Ubuntu and I'll give you the code to install the network driver from the console after step 5. Then reboot and hopefully you will have networking enabled.

Comment: $lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:
Network controller [0280]. Broadcom Inc. and and subsidiaries Device [14e4:43c3] (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:86fb]
Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
Kernel modules: brcmfmac

I am on cable and the motherboard is a MSI Z87-GD65.
Furthermore, I have a wireless internet adapter: "Asus pce-ac88"

Comment: [Asus PCE-AC88 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072676/) The answer to [WiFi Driver Issues ASUS_PCE-AC88](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907489/) by chili555 also tells you how to install the Broadcom driver.

Comment: I do not want to waste time installing the wifi adapter right now as It is straight forward once Ubuntu is running again. Instead I want to install the motherboard ethernet controller.

I have removed my wireless adapter from my PC. Now the Ethernet controller is a Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220X gigabit Ethernet controller
Kernel driver in use: alx
kernel modules: alx.

I assume this adapter is not working.

Comment: [internet died after ubuntu 16.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894418/i)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894418/i does not work.

Comment: [Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278182)

Comment: Does not work either. command "ethtool" not found

Answer (score 0):

Since my eth0  was not working, I could not follow @karels answer. I decided to get a new Ubuntu intallation using a USB drive.

Thanks for the help